# Default selection not working when selectionLimit: 1 in angularjs dropdown multiselct

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multi-select

I am using angularjs dropdown  multiselect,I have a problem when I am trying to set default selection of the dropdown when the selection limit is 1 it's not working.
 and that's my code:

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="idPropertyData"
     selected-model="idPropertyModel" 
     extra-settings="idPropertySettings">
</div>
```

//javascript

```js
$scope.idPropertyModel = [{
"id": 1
 }];
$scope.idPropertyData = [ { id: 1, label: 'David' }, 
{ id: 2, label: 'Jhon' 
}, { id: 3, label: 'Danny' }, ];
$scope.idPropertySettings = { 
selectionLimit: 1,
 };
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The `ng-dropdown-multiselect` directive is not a core AngularJS directive. Please either provide the code or a link if it is a third-party library.

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/1.11.8/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js

Comment: http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/